# How to sort sub documents in MongoDB by index in reverse order without updating the actual array

Tags: mongodb

Here is a sub document in MongoDB:

```
 "comment_history" : [ 
        "A", 
        "B", 
        "C", 
    ]
```

I want to get something like this

```
 "comment_history" : [ 
        "C", 
        "B", 
        "A", 
    ]
```

Comment: You can specify `-1` in your `sort` for descending or reverse order sorting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sort array in query and project all fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888885/sort-array-in-query-and-project-all-fields)

Comment: Did you try putting your question title into google first? Because the update modifer for [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) comes right up at the top if your intention is to "store" in that order always. And if you just wanted it in "results" only ( without modifying ) then a little searching should have led you to [`$reverseArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reverseArray/). But your question does not really say which of these you actually mean.

Comment: I need array in reverse order without updating that array.

Answer (score 0):

With mongodb 3.4 you can use "$reverseArray" operator

```
  db.posts.aggregate([
    {
     $project:
      {
         title: 1,
         comment_history: { $reverseArray: "$comment_history" }
      }
    }
    ])
```